# Decomposable Modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, modules

I have a question relating to modules over rings:
 "Find a decomposition of of the module $\mathbb{Z}/10\mathbb{Z}$ over the ring $\mathbb{Z}$ into a direct sum of indecomposable modules." I understand the definition of a module and indecomposable module but am having trouble going about this question. Also how would I show a module such as $M=\{0,2,4,6,8\}$ is decomposable/indecomposable?

Comment: So this $M$ has **five** elements?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Yes, I feel like I'm missing an important piece of information here.

Comment: You know that $5$ is a prime number?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown So any module with a prime number of elements is indecomposable?

Comment: $\Bbb Z$-modules are just Abelian groups. So this example is just elementary group theory....

Comment: Do you remember the Chinese remainder theorem?